# What are the differences between a template and a function pointer for a Strategy design pattern in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I'm implementing a Strategy Design Pattern in c++, and I've found a couple of different options I could take. One route would be to use a template, and might look like this:

```
namespace Strategies
{
    struct IsEven
    {
        bool doSomething(int x) { return x % 2 == 0; }
    };

    struct IsOdd
    {
        bool doSomething(int y) { return y % 2 == 1; }
    };
}


template<typename Strategy>
class Processor
{
public:
    Processor() : _strat{ Strategy() }
    {}

    bool process(int num)
    {
        return _strat.doSomething(num);
    }

private:
    Strategy _strat;
};

int main()
{
    Processor<Strategies::IsEven> templateOne{};
    Processor<Strategies::IsOdd> templateTwo{};
    std::cout << "Process 4 with One: " << (templateOne.process(4) ? "True" : "False") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Process 4 with Two: " << (templateTwo.process(4) ? "True" : "False") << std::endl;
}
```

Another route would be to use function pointers, and might look like this:

```
#include <functional>

class ProcessorTwo
{
public:
    using StrategyFunction = std::function<bool(int)>;
    static bool lessThanFive(int num) {
        return num < 5;
    }

    static bool greaterThanFive(int num) {
        return num > 5;
    }

    ProcessorTwo(StrategyFunction strat) : _strat{ strat }
    {}

    bool process(int num) {
        return _strat(num);
    }
    
private:
    StrategyFunction _strat;
};

int main()
{
    ProcessorTwo functionPointerOne{ ProcessorTwo::greaterThanFive };
    ProcessorTwo functionPointerTwo{ ProcessorTwo::lessThanFive };
    std::cout << "Process 4 with One: " << (functionPointerOne.process(4) ? "True" : "False") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Process 4 with Two: " << (functionPointerTwo.process(4) ? "True" : "False") << std::endl;
}
```

I will know the functions that will be used at compile time. I'm new enough to c++ that I don't really understand what the differences between these two approaches would be. I've heard function pointers add a layer of indirection, but wouldn't the same also be true of a struct holding the function? Is there a more "idiomatic" c++ option, or does it just come down to developer preference?

Comment: As it is implemented within a class possibly one drawback of templates might be that instances of `ProcessorOne<StratA>` and `ProcessorOne<StratB>` will not be polymorphic to each other, while in `ProcessorTwo` all instances are polymorphic (although this could be solved by a common ancestor). There is also that `ProcessorTwo` can be implemented separately, while `One` requires implementation in a header

Comment: @Lala5th the templates not being polymorphic isn’t something I had thought about. That means if I ever wanted to make an array or vector with ProcessorOne they would all need the same strategy, right?

Comment: It's generally more productive to minimize the amount of time that gets devoted to Buzzword Bingo, and instead of focus on actually studying all of these C++ fundamentals. Once it is better understood the underlying nuts and bolts of templates and function pointers, it will become more clear when one or the other approach works better in a given situation. There is no universal law that says that X is always better than Y. One of the two approaches will work better in certain, specific situations, the other than others. Fully understanding both is how the right choice always gets made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is the template version uses "compile time polymorphism" meaning the selection of the strategy happens at compile time and the strategy is part of the type. Thus, the strategy a particular instance of `Processor<T>` uses must be known at compile time and cannot be changed dynamically after a `Processor<T>` is created.

You could add a member function, however, to make it so the strategy used by a `ProcessorTwo` can be changed dynamically. You could also write, say, a function that takes a `std::function<bool(int)>` as an argument and creates a `ProcessorTwo` with it in the function's body; you couldn't do this with a `Processor<T>` unless it was a function template.

So if you need that kind of dynamism a function pointer or `std::function` based approach is the way to go, but if you don't need it then the template version will be more efficient because calling the strategy will not involve runtime indirection.

Comment: The template version also compiles the code in every compilation unit that uses it while the function pointer version can use a separate compilation unit for the code. The compiler/linker later tries to merge instances of the functions that are identical but it's in no way guaranteed that you get less than one copy of the code per template type used. On the other hand you can get better optimization for each type since the type will be known at compile time and skip the indirection through the function pointer. Both methods have advantages.